# ionic 2: login with google+ works in browser but not in smartphone

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view, ionic-popup

i succee to do login with google+ into my app.
when i check it in chrome\explorer when i run my app it works fine,
but when i check into my smartphone or emulator of android it shows me login successful toaster(pop up) but it stay in the same page of login without doing nothing.(it's just happen when i press on login with google +).

**in addition,when i press login with invalid details it's shows the icon loading and it stuck.**

this is my code:
app.module.ts => [app.module.ts code](http://pastebin.com/FCFkAV7D)

app.component.ts=>[app.component.ts](http://pastebin.com/a3Yc1wH7)

this is my service provider code: [service ts code](http://pastebin.com/h3frv2MP)

this is my login page code: [login.ts](http://pastebin.com/3S3ABUnL)

[image: loading while invalid login details- loading without shows any error pop up of user\password not correct and it stuck]
[image: while press on google+ shows user successful but without enter to home page--> in browser it's works fine.]

***photos from my smartphone***

**first photo:
loading while invalid login details- loading without shows any error pop up of user\password not correct and it stuck**

**second photo:while press on google+ shows user successful but without enter to home page--> in browser it's works fine.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `signInWithPopup()` or `signInWithRedirect()` inside Ionic/Cordova apps, or at least not yet.

The workaround you need for that is to use the Google cordova plugin as stated by [Mike](https://twitter.com/mhartington) in the [Ionic Blog](http://blog.ionic.io/google-oauth-changes/)

You use the plugin to get the login credentials, and then you pass those credentials to Firebase's `signInWithCredential()` method and that way you authenticate the user.